# Waiting for asynchronous implementations, of an interface

Tags: java, asynchronous

currently i have to use an Interface of a Service. The interface provides the follwing methods:

```
public interface SomeServiceInterface{    
   // true - if the implementation of the interface is an asynchronous call, 
   // false - if synchronous
    boolean isAsynchronous();

    // a method, that can be implemented synchronously and asynchrounously
    // it returns some response object
    ResponseObject someMethod();
}
```

And a simple object:

```
public class ResponseObject{
    private String foo;
    private int bar;
}
```

The implementation of that interface is hidden for me and i can't touch it. Now i have a method in my class, that is getting a list of type `SomeServiceInterface`. I would like to wait for asynchrounous service operation as for synchronous operations.

I need something like:

```
public oneOfMyImplementedMethod(){
// Getting a reference
List<SomeServiceInterface> serviceList = ...
   for(SomeServiceInterface service: serviceList){
      ResponseObject responseObject = null;
      if(service.isAsynchronous()){
         // !!! Here i want to wait until the asynchronous operation is finished, instead to continue
         responseObject = responseObject.someMethod();
      }
      else{
         responseObject = service.someMethod();
      }
      //... do something with the responseObject
   }
}
```

How can i achieve this? I am new to this asynchronous topic and I have seen alrady some people are using [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). But i'am not able to transfer it correctly to my situation. Can somebody help me? Or maybe i have to use something different?

I would be glad for your help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you know when you can call `responseObject.someMethod()`?

Comment: Ideally, an asynchronous operation should have a callback that is called when the operation is finished. According to your interface it doesn't seem to be the case. Have you a way of knowing if the operation is terminated or not ?

Comment: Like the other say: your interface does not hold up to the claims you are making. It should either allow for call backs; or return some kind of Future or Promise ... in the sense of: that interface doesnt give you any means to understand **when** that asynchronous call has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not wait until an asynchronous method returns, because its nature. It does all the work behind the scenes. In order to know when the work is done you need a callback method. You can register an event handler that will be triggered when the job is done.

```
public interface SomeServiceInterface{  
    boolean isAsynchronous();

    ResponseObject someMethod();

    void addEventHandler(MyProcessEventHandler h);
}
```

And you event handler could be something like this.

```
public class MyProcessEventHandler{  

      public void onEvent(ProcessResult result){//Process result could be a class that holds the result of the process.
          //Do the work here. Here you process the result of the process call.
      }
}
```